GraphQL Shopify API, return query filters
I'm using the GraphQL of shopify for search products and retrieve the handle, this is the data i use in my requests in my python code.
data = {
        "query": f"""
            {{
              products(first: {MAX_SIZE}, query: {my_query} ) {{
                edges {{
                  node {{
                    handle
                  }}
                }}
              }}
            }}
            """
    }

Everything work as aspected. The variable my_query contains many OR filters.
I would like to know if is possible returns inside the node, with the handle, which one of the filters was right for the product.
I try to search online but i didn't find a solution.
Thanks to all.

Unclear what you're asking.

in the my_query variable I have many OR conditions, I would like to return with each product the condition that satisfied it
